# Linear independence conditioning and test

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Phi =\{\phi_0(x)\,\phi_1(x)\,\phi_2(x)\}$ be a set in some vector space $V$, with the inner product $\langle f(x),g(x) \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cdot g(x)dx$.
Assuming I want to test for [Linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) (the link only refers to vector spaces), is it correct to say that $\Phi$ is Linear independent iff $\forall \phi_i(x),\phi_j(x) \in \Phi \exists \langle \phi_i(x),\phi_j(x) \rangle=0 \forall i\neq j|i,j\in \mathbb N$?

What other methods can I generally apply to test for Linear independence?

Comment: What is the condition $<\phi_i(x),\phi_j(x)>$

Comment: Do you mean 
$$\langle \phi_i(x),\phi_j(x) \rangle\neq 0,\  \forall i\neq j \quad ?$$

Comment: @MichaelChapman sorry. see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not true that 3 vectors needs to be orthogonal to be linearly independent. For example, look at $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the vectors $(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ and the standart inner product. 
In your case you can take $\phi_1(x)=\chi_{[0,2]},\phi_2(x)=\chi_{[1,3]},\phi_3(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}+\chi_{[2,3]}$

Comment: $\chi_I(x)=1$ if $x\in{I}$ and $0$ otherwise